# resume running a script after function call

Tags: bash, function

I am writing a script which displays input options in a while loop provided by a function `user_input()` and set values depending on user input, then I call another function `user_info()`. If a user made a mistake I am trying to offer him to go back to correct his input. So if a user set `$var` by mistake to "Yes" he can go back an reset the option! Assuming the user reset `$var` to "No", is there any way not to resume at `code (2)`, rather to jump to the `elif` statement and run `code (3)` ? If the question is not clear I can post my code to make it clearer. Thanks a lot:

```
user_input(){
    while true; do
        input option $var
    done
    user_info
}

user_info(){
    some code
    if [ "${var}" = "Yes" ]; then
        code (1)
        if [ "${option}" = "back" ]; then
            user_input
        fi
        code (2)
    elif [ "${var}" = "No" ]; then
        code (3)
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution by adding return after each call of the `user_input()` function like this, please correct me if I made a mistake. Thanks a lot:

```
user_input(){
    while true; do
        input option $var
    done
    user_info
}

user_info(){
    some code
    if [ "${var}" = "Yes" ]; then
        code (1)
        if [ "${option}" = "back" ]; then
            user_input
            return
        fi
        code (2)
    elif [ "${var}" = "No" ]; then
        code (3)
    fi
}
```